# Border-property of css is not working in addClass() jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css, border

I am trying to addClass to a button in jquery. In that class I changed background and border color of button. background color is working fine but border property is not working

```js
$("#price-filter1").addClass('active-filter-bg')
```

```css
.filter-btn.active-filter-bg {
  background-color: #ecb7c1;
  border: solid 1px transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a type="button" id="price-filter1" class="filter-btn">$0 - $20</a>
```

Comment: How do you know that `border property` is not working?

Comment: Your border is "transparent" - what exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: Changing border from gray to invisible

Comment: It's working just fine when I test, Also you forgot to add the class where you have gray border in your example. missing information like that is much needed

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uyzdb0pg/) with the added grey border.   Please update your question to include all the information, see [mcve].  Seems to work just fine, so your snippet in the question needs to *demonstrate* the issue.

Comment: *if* (so, a guess) your css was originally `border: solid 1px #333 !important;` then no, it won't update it.  https://jsfiddle.net/uyzdb0pg/1/  that's what `!important` is for.

Comment: It's working properly. The reason that it doesn't show is that its color is transparent. try other color to test it out.